# Making button work in fragment as opposed to activity

Tags: android

I can make a button work in my **Activities**, but I am having trouble with making a button eventlistener work in my **Fragment**. Can someone please help me spot where the error is?. I have tried for a long time now. about 4 hours, but I cannot figure out what i do wrong.

```
package com.fistats.fistats.util;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.fistats.fistats.MainActivity;
import com.fistats.fistats.R;
import com.fistats.fistats.remoteCom;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class CreateEx extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
private static final String EXER_URL = "THE URL";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
private EditText name, muscle, remedy, description;
private Button create;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private RelativeLayout theOne;
remoteCom rC = new remoteCom();


public CreateEx() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    theOne = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_createex, container, false);
    name = (EditText) theOne.findViewById(R.id.Ex);
    muscle = (EditText) theOne.findViewById(R.id.mu);
    description = (EditText) theOne.findViewById(R.id.des);
    remedy = (EditText) theOne.findViewById(R.id.rem);
    create = (Button)theOne.findViewById(R.id.saex);
    create.setOnClickListener(this);

    return theOne;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        new CreateIt().execute();


}

class CreateIt extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating User...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        String nameIn = name.getText().toString();
        String muscleIn = muscle.getText().toString();
        String descriptionIn = description.getText().toString();
        String remedyIn = remedy.getText().toString();
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", nameIn));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("muscle", muscleIn));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", descriptionIn));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("remedies", remedyIn));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");

            //Posting user data to script
            JSONObject json = rC.makeHttpRequest(EXER_URL, "POST", params);

            // full json response
            Log.d("Exercise reg attempt", json.toString());

            // json success element
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Exercise Created!", json.toString());
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                Log.d("submitting failed!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }
    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

}

This is what happens in the log:

```
02-20 10:24:12.085    1930-1930/com.fistats.fistats I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
02-20 10:24:12.214    1930-1949/com.fistats.fistats D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
02-20 10:24:12.256    1930-1930/com.fistats.fistats D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6b04350, tid 1930
02-20 10:24:12.333    1930-1930/com.fistats.fistats D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
02-20 10:24:12.431    1930-1949/com.fistats.fistats D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6b04580, tid 1949
02-20 10:24:12.517    1930-1949/com.fistats.fistats I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-20 10:24:12.572    1930-1949/com.fistats.fistats D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
02-20 10:24:12.594    1930-1949/com.fistats.fistats W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-20 10:24:12.594    1930-1949/com.fistats.fistats W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6b4d400, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-20 10:24:13.307    1930-1949/com.fistats.fistats W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-20 10:24:13.307    1930-1949/com.fistats.fistats W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6b4d400, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-20 10:24:15.467    1930-1949/com.fistats.fistats W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-20 10:24:15.467    1930-1949/com.fistats.fistats W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xae0f87a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-20 10:24:16.348    1930-1949/com.fistats.fistats W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-20 10:24:16.348    1930-1949/com.fistats.fistats W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa52f89e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-20 10:24:59.099    1930-2277/com.fistats.fistats D/request!﹕ starting
02-20 10:24:59.139    1930-1949/com.fistats.fistats W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-20 10:24:59.139    1930-1949/com.fistats.fistats W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa52f8ae0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-20 10:24:59.187    1930-2277/com.fistats.fistats D/Login attempt﹕ {"success":1,"message":"Login successful!"}
02-20 10:24:59.187    1930-2277/com.fistats.fistats D/Login Successful!﹕ {"success":1,"message":"Login successful!"}
02-20 10:24:59.387    1930-1949/com.fistats.fistats W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-20 10:24:59.387    1930-1949/com.fistats.fistats W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa5575420, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-20 10:25:01.331    1930-1949/com.fistats.fistats W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-20 10:25:01.331    1930-1949/com.fistats.fistats W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa55757a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-20 10:25:01.341    1930-1930/com.fistats.fistats I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 117 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 10:25:03.681    1930-1930/com.fistats.fistats I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 141 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 10:30:54.986    1930-1930/com.fistats.fistats W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
02-20 10:31:50.831    2367-2383/com.fistats.fistats D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
02-20 10:31:50.833    2367-2367/com.fistats.fistats D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa601d380, tid 2367
02-20 10:31:50.913    2367-2367/com.fistats.fistats D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
02-20 10:31:50.989    2367-2383/com.fistats.fistats D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa601d660, tid 2383
02-20 10:31:51.064    2367-2383/com.fistats.fistats I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-20 10:31:51.130    2367-2383/com.fistats.fistats D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
02-20 10:31:51.139    2367-2383/com.fistats.fistats W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-20 10:31:51.139    2367-2383/com.fistats.fistats W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa602c600, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-20 10:31:53.962    2367-2383/com.fistats.fistats W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-20 10:31:53.962    2367-2383/com.fistats.fistats W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa602c620, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-20 10:31:55.262    2367-2386/com.fistats.fistats D/request!﹕ starting
02-20 10:31:55.287    2367-2383/com.fistats.fistats W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-20 10:31:55.288    2367-2383/com.fistats.fistats W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa5376120, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-20 10:31:55.339    2367-2386/com.fistats.fistats D/Login attempt﹕ {"success":1,"message":"Login successful!"}
02-20 10:31:55.339    2367-2386/com.fistats.fistats D/Login Successful!﹕ {"success":1,"message":"Login successful!"}
02-20 10:31:55.806    2367-2379/com.fistats.fistats I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7148(404KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 2MB/2MB, paused 11.046ms total 25.204ms
02-20 10:31:56.547    2367-2367/com.fistats.fistats I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 10:31:56.582    2367-2383/com.fistats.fistats W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-20 10:31:56.582    2367-2383/com.fistats.fistats W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa53a1200, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-20 10:31:56.661    2367-2383/com.fistats.fistats W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-20 10:31:56.661    2367-2383/com.fistats.fistats W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa602c620, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

Comment: Try to call the getActivity().finish() after the Task

Comment: If you call getActivity().finish() it will finish entire Activity.

Comment: No errors are displayed

Comment: what happening when you click on button?

Comment: you need to move this line: create.setOnClickListener(this); to onActivityCreated(Bundle)

Comment: after return statement you execute asyncktask..so try to call it before return

Comment: Try to put all the variable creation into the method OnViewCreated instead of onCreateView.

Comment: was your problem resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to finish your activity before the task has finished? You are initializing a progress dialog using the activity as the context:

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
```

And that happens after you called finish on activity. I think you should do your task and when it ends call activity.finish on onPostExecute. If you want to close the activity and keep the task alive you have to pass the application context to ProgressDialog

Comment: That was a mistake. It was not supposed to be there. I have corrected it but it does not fix the problem

Comment: Have you tried to pass applicationContext instead of activity?

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need to have on the onCreateView method

```
return (inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_createex,container,false));
```

you then need to override onActivityCreated and declare all your widgets like:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle){
    super.onActivityCreated(bundle)
    name = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Ex);
    muscle = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mu);
    description = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.des);
    remedy = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rem);
    create = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.saex);
    create.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```